# Suspected std::array C++11 library is broken? What do I do?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

From google I can't seem to find clear answers, But I don't know what to do. I suspected there might be a problem in a larger program I was writing with the array C++11 library for g++ and wrote a test program. I am using g++ 4.8.1.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
int main()
{
    std::array<int,5> vector;

    return 0;
}
```

My test command line compile is:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

with errors..

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:107:12: error: 'array' has not been declared
       swap(array& __other)
            ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array: In member function 'void std::Array<_Tp, _Nm>::swap(int&)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:109:50: error: request for member 'begin' in '__other', which is of non-class type 'int'
       { std::swap_ranges(begin(), end(), __other.begin()); }
                                                  ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array: At global scope:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:228:22: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                      ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:228:27: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:228:74: error: 'bool std::operator==(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:233:22: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator!=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                      ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:233:27: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator!=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:233:74: error: 'bool std::operator!=(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator!=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:238:21: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator<(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __a, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __b)
                     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:238:26: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator<(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __a, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __b)
                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:238:69: error: 'bool std::operator<(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator<(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __a, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __b)
                                                                     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:246:21: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator>(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:246:26: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator>(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:246:73: error: 'bool std::operator>(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator>(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                                         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:251:22: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator<=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                      ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:251:27: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator<=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:251:74: error: 'bool std::operator<=(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator<=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:256:22: error: 'array' does not name a type
     operator>=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                      ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:256:27: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     operator>=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:256:74: error: 'bool std::operator>=(int)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
     operator>=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:10: error: variable or field 'swap' declared void
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:10: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:19: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:27: error: '__one' was not declared in this scope
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:34: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                  ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:43: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:262:51: error: '__two' was not declared in this scope
     swap(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
                                                   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:268:9: error: template declaration of 'constexpr _Tp& std::get'
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:268:9: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:268:18: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
                  ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:268:26: error: '__arr' was not declared in this scope
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
                          ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:277:9: error: template declaration of 'constexpr _Tp&& std::get'
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>&& __arr) noexcept
         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:277:9: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:277:18: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>&& __arr) noexcept
                  ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:277:27: error: label '__arr' referenced outside of any function
     get(array<_Tp, _Nm>&& __arr) noexcept
                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:277:27: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:285:15: error: 'array' does not name a type
     get(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
               ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:285:20: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     get(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
                    ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array: In function 'constexpr const _Tp& std::get(int)':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:289:9: error: '__arr' was not declared in this scope
  _S_ref(__arr._M_elems, _Int);
         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:38:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array: At global scope:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:306:23: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
     struct tuple_size<_GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:306:23: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:306:50: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
     struct tuple_size<_GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                                                  ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:303:11: error: provided for 'template<class _Tp> class std::tuple_size'
     class tuple_size;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:306:53: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     struct tuple_size<_GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                                                     ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:38:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:314:32: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
     struct tuple_element<_Int, _GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                                ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:314:32: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:314:59: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)
     struct tuple_element<_Int, _GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                                                           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:311:11: error: provided for 'template<unsigned int _Int, class _Tp> class std::tuple_element'
     class tuple_element;
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array:314:62: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
     struct tuple_element<_Int, _GLIBCXX_STD_C::array<_Tp, _Nm>>
                                                              ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:2: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
  std::array<int,5> vector;
  ^
main.cpp:5:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  std::array<int,5> vector;
             ^
main.cpp:5:13: error: expected ';' before 'int'
```

And clearly from the error, there is a lot of reference to the std::array file that i have included which seems to be the source of the error. What do I do?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: added compilation commands and g++ version.

Comment: Which version of g++?

Comment: FYI, std::array is not the same as std::vector

Comment: @OMGtechy, yes. did I mix the two up somewhere?

Comment: You named your std::array vector, which may have implied that you thought they were interchangable.

Comment: @user27886 A `std::vector` is a standard C++ class.  It isn't wise to name your variables the same as a C++ class.

Comment: You could try `g++ -E whatever.cc | less` and search for the array class... see what's going on.  Just guessing, but there might be a `#define` or something that you can set that will fix it, assuming it's some error in platform-specific code selection.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Ah yes I see that could have been confusing. All the same, I do believe there is a genuine error with std::array. I did not use std::vector anywhere in the test program.

Comment: @user27886 - In this case, you were lucky.  However, you cannot predict what a header may or may not `#include`.  Just because you're not explicitly using a certain type doesn't mean one of the headers doesn't introduce that type somewhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It's totally valid for him to name the variable `vector`. He's not bringing `std::vector` into scope with a  `using` declaration. I wouldn't call this "lucky." Yes, it's good to avoid confusing identifiers, but I think people are being a little too nit-picky here.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/   grab the 4.8.1 posix-threads with sjlj (for compiling both x86 and x64).

Comment: @Cornstalks: He didn't see it wasn't valid, he said it wasn't *wise* (and he's right).

Comment: `void std::Array<_Tp, _Nm>::swap(int&)'`...hmm, that's odd. Open `c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\array` and go to line 81 or so, does it say `struct array` or `struct Array`?

Comment: I see no errors with gcc 4.8.2 and with clang 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) both on mac

Comment: unable to reproduce with [g++ 4.8.1 at Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ndea6J). the error messages are consistent with *not* providing option `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you don't provide `-std=c++11`, and attempt to include `<array>` you'd [get a different and much cleaner error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0608981da9663c8b).

Comment: Yes @T.C. it is indeed capital `struct Array` when looking in the array file! I changed it to lower case `struct array` and it compiled fine! but what does that mean? Should I just update my gcc to 4.8.2 as pyCthon has done? Why would it be capitalized? That seems like a really silly mistake to be in the standard library.

Comment: @T.C.: the error list doesn't stop there: it [continues with exactly the OP's quoted errors](http://ideone.com/zjmjWk)

Comment: @user27886 I'm not sure where you got your distro, since this typo shouldn't have made it past the simplest tests. If you'd never opened `<array>` before this, I'd consider using a better MinGW distribution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But not his first bazillion lines of errors.

Comment: @EdS.: I was replying to the [second comment of Paul's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234986/suspected-stdarray-c11-library-is-broken-what-do-i-do?noredirect=1#comment39311044_25234986). That comment makes it sound like some stroke of shear luck that this works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out somehow a typo made its way into OP's `<array>`. What should have been

```
template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
  struct array
  {
```

became

```
template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
  struct Array
  {
```

Causing a bazillion compiler errors as it tries to process the rest of `<array>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid C++11 program.

The error you got is most probably due to dialect selection: the C++98 mode does not provide `std::array` container. See the docs at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Specifically, your error comes down to the following:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:2: error: 'array' is not a member of 'std'
  std::array<int,5> vector;
  ^
main.cpp:5:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  std::array<int,5> vector;
             ^
main.cpp:5:13: error: expected ';' before 'int'
```

So, just add `-std=c++11` to the command line and things should work.

Comment: You'd see a different error if that were the problem: `/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

Answer (score 0):

unable to reproduce with [g++ 4.8.1 at Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ndea6J):

[image]

the error messages are consistent with *not* providing option `-std=c++11`

add that option to the command line