# C++ wrapper class holding raw array of non-trivially constructed objects

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, templates, c++11

This is a little hard to describe in words, I'll start with a snippet and try to explain what is attempted as best I can.

```
struct NonTrivialBase {
    virtual void TakeAction();
    virtual ~NonTrivialBase();
};

template< typename P >
struct NonTrivial_D1 : NonTrivialBase
{
    P case1;

    virtual void TakeAction() {
        // do something with case1
    }

    NonTrivial_D1( P arg ) : case1(arg) {
    }
};

template< typename Q >
struct NonTrivial_D2 : NonTrivialBase
{
    Q case2;

    virtual void TakeAction() {
        // do something with case2
    }

    NonTrivial_D2( Q arg, int arg2 ) : case2(arg,arg2) {
    }
};

class Unit
{
    NonTrivialBase * Member;

  public:

    template< typename P2 >
    Unit (P2 par) : Member ( new NonTrivial_D1<P2>(par) ) {}

    template< typename Q2 >
    Unit (Q2 par, int par2) : Member ( new NonTrivial_D2<Q2>(par,par2) ) {}
};

template< unsigned short Count >
class Collection
{
    Unit units[ Count ];

  public:

    template< typename P3 >
    Collection( P3 par )
    //  : units { [ 0 ... Count - 1 ] = {par} }
    // ^^ problem
    {}

    template< typename Q3 >
    Collection( Q3 par, int arg )
    //  : units { [ 0 ... Count - 1 ] = {par, arg} }
    // ^^ problem
    {}

};
```

If it isn't clear (may not be) I'm trying to come up with a container class that can initialize an array of non-trivially-constructed objects, all of which will have the same parameters to whichever constructor is deemed valid. The essence of the design is `Collection` and `Unit` have the same constructors in order to manage a compile-time-known number of identically-constructed "units" only through `Collection` references.

For various reasons it is not possible to initialize `Unit` without a constructor. Both `Collection` and `Unit` classes are intended to act as base classes themselves.

I expect something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950796/5134012) to work but again, `std::array` is not available in my environment (GCC 4.8.1-4 / MinGW) and I want to avoid if possible including other libraries *just* for this one thing. Boost isn't an option for me, for example.

Then, the array-initializer syntax itself.

I understand this is GCC-only but that isn't a problem. I can't even get the syntax to behave correctly when the array-element type requires template parameters for the constructor (automatically determined or not, I can live with either). I get an error to the equivalent of:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
: units { [ 0 ... Count - 1 ] = {par} }
            ^
```

I believe that the array-range initializer in and of itself should be supported, courtesy of [this reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

And lastly I just need to be clear that this solution is not scalable because of `Count`

```
Unit units[Count] = { {param}, {param}, ... }
```

such as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34502344/5134012).

In the grand scheme of things I don't *have to* do it this way but now that I have had the idea, I'm genuinely curious how to approach this...

Relevant GCC parameters (just in case) - `g++ -std=gnu++0x -O3 -Wall -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0`

**EDIT**

To clarify some requirements -

Heap vs Stack - preference is for stack but I can live with heap-based solutions. Bear in mind Unit may not be copyable.

`std::array` - I cannot use this. The suggested duplicate **relies on** this being available.

Comment: Using `std::vector` would be the simplest solution

Comment: @milleniumbug and not the same thing. a "stack"-allocated array is not the same as a "heap"-allocated array!

Comment: @rubenvb Which is not really relevant here. At least not until OP adds a hard requirement for it.

Comment: @Xeren also, GCC 4.8.1 does have a functional `<array>`, it seems you stumbled upon a broken build, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234986/suspected-stdarray-c11-library-is-broken-what-do-i-do). I highly recommend either fixing the typo in the `array` header file or just getting a non-broken toolchain. Also, get a MinGW-w64 version from here: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net.

Comment: @milleniumbug to confirm (it's late and I'm losing my mind on this) using `std::vector` would be heap-based? In that case I'd just loop-construct in `Collection`'s constructors via emplace?

Comment: @rubenvb checked just now, it's not a typo, it is indeed `struct array`. However inspecting the header the whole thing is hidden in preprocessing due to `__cplusplus < 201103L` cutting off the definition in favor of a c++0x_warning.h file (it is 199711L for reasons I dont know)

Comment: @XerenNarcy Try compiling with `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=gnu0x`. Also, the linked solution works for anything that is initializable from an initializer list. Although that then precludes initializing non-copyable objects (init lists take a copy of the value).

Comment: @XerenNarcy Yup, it's heap-based. With `std::vector` you could call `vec.reserve(Count);` and then call `Unit unit = { par }; vec.push_back(unit);` in a loop.

Comment: @rubenvb mkay... tried it, no luck in fact breaks things further such as this for whatever reason - `c:\mingw\include\math.h: In function 'float hypotf(float, float)':
c:\mingw\include\math.h:635:30: error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope
 { return (float)(_hypot (x, y)); }` . I had it to gnu for a reason lol...

Comment: @milleniumbug Thanks, I think without going insane making this work on my environment, that's probably going to be as elegant as possible under the circumstances.